# How can I scan the classes that implement a certain class of my library in Python?

Tags: python, class

I'm building a library to ease the development of event-driven architectures in python. My library has two classes that the project that wishes to use it must implement: `Event` and `EventSchema`. `EventSchema` defines how to serialize (with marshmallow) the `Event` class.

I have another class, the `EventSerializer`, whose job is: given a json that must contain a property called `event_type_name`, deserialize it into the proper `Event` instance. In order to achieve that, the user must supply a dictionary with the maps between their custom `Events` and their respective `Schemas`.

This is an example of such instantiation:

```
# A derived schema
class EventMineSchema(EventSchema):
    data = fields.Dict()
    id = fields.Integer()

    @post_load
    def create_event_mine(self, data):
        return EventMine(data['data'], data['id'])

# A derived event
class EventMine(Event):
    event_type_name = 'event_mine'

    def __init__(self, data, id):
        Event.__init__(self, self.event_type_name)
        self.data = data
        self.id = id

    def set_status(self, status):
        self.data['status'] = status

    def get_status(self):
        return self.data['status']

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

# Initialize the event serializer
EventSerializer.instance().initialize({
    EventMine.event_type_name: EventMineSchema()
})
```

I would wish to save the user of this hassle of having him to provide these mappings manually. I would wish to have a parameterless `initialize` method which, in its implementation, scans all the subclasses of `Event` and `EventSchema` and, based on a naming convention, map automatically the respective Events with their schemas.

I come from a .NET background and doing this with reflection is rather easy. How would I do this in Python? I've tried using the `Event.__subclasses__()` approach which works well... if the user has manually imported the classes prior to call the initialization of the `EventSerializer`. I would wish to not force the user to do anything at all if possible other than call the initialize method of my library.

These are the definition of the main classes in action:

```
class EventSchema(Schema):
    event_type_name = fields.Str()
    occurred_on = fields.Date()


class Event:

    # A constant that subscriber can use in their "listens_to" events to
    # tell they are interested in all the events that happen on their topic
    ALL = 'ALL'

    event_type_name = 'Default'

    def __init__(self, event_type_name='Default', occurred_on=datetime.now()):
        self.occurred_on = occurred_on
        self.event_type_name = event_type_name

    def get_occurred_on(self):
        return self.occurred_on

    def get_event_type_name(self):
        return self.event_type_name

@Singleton
class EventSerializer:
    def __init__(self):
        current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
        a = Event.__subclasses__()
        for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
            if inspect.isclass(obj):
                print(obj)

        self.event_serializer_map = {}

    def initialize(self, event_serializer_map):
        self.event_serializer_map = event_serializer_map

    def deserialize(self, event_dict):
        event_type_name = event_dict['event_type_name']

        if event_type_name not in self.event_serializer_map:
            raise ValueError("The event type {} doesn't have a registered serializer")

        schema = self.event_serializer_map[event_type_name]
        return schema.load(event_dict).data

    def serialize(self, event):

        event_type_name = event.event_type_name

        if event_type_name not in self.event_serializer_map:
            raise ValueError("The event type {} doesn't have a registered serializer")

        schema = self.event_serializer_map[event_type_name]
        return schema.dumps(event).data
```

Comment: Why not make the serialization a classmethod of the schema and use a decorator to enumerate?

Comment: Also, as a (partial) answer, metaclasses.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could you post an example of such usage to illustrate?

Comment: I've linked to this before, but Marty Alchin has a [really elegant implementation](http://martyalchin.com/2008/jan/10/simple-plugin-framework/) of this; it uses metaclasses, as Ignacio suggests.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the post seems really interesting and very similar to what I need. I'll take some time to study it. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've read the post you mentioned. It's really interesting but that doesn't seem to avoid the fact that the plugins need to be somehow imported through an import clause somewhere in order to be recognized. Is that true? If so, with __subclasses__() I could achieve the same result (although maybe less neater)

Comment: You can't really do anything without importing things; Python can't possibly know about the code unless it's executed. That's just the way a dynamic language works. One possibility is to use some kind of predictable file structure so that the classes can be discovered automatically.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to look at what is currently imported.

You're currently querying `sys.modules.keys()` for module names, or you could use `globals()`, and you can interrogate each item with `dir()`.

For a given class you can learn about its immediate children with e.g. `EventSchema.__subclasses__()`. Recurse to find all descendants.

Comment: I think `__subclasses__` only works if the user has previously imported the code, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You could use `imp` to load a module if necessary. You could choose to scan `sys.path` directories for files matching a pattern.